# Domain of a partial derivative in two variables

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I have a function $f$ from $R^2$ to $R$ such that $f(x,y) = |xy|$ and I need to find the domain of its partial derivative with respect to x.

So I know that $f_x = y$ when $xy > 0$ and that $f_x = -y$ when $xy>0$

I am struggling figuring out what the domain of $f_x$ is, how should  I reason in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Well, given that you've been able to compute $f_x$ in the cases where $xy<0$ and where $xy > 0$, all points $(x,y)$ with $xy \ne 0$ should definitely be in the domain of $f_x$. All that remains to do is understand $f_x$ when $xy = 0$.

There are two cases here: if $xy=0$, then either $x = 0$ or $y = 0$. These cases should be considered separately. Ask yourself: does the derivative exist at these points?

One way to do it is to check whether the limits exist:
$$
   \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|h \cdot y| - |0 \cdot y|}{h}
$$
(for the $x=0$ case)
$$
    \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|(x+h) \cdot 0| - |x \cdot 0|}{h}
$$
(for the $y=0$ case).